# unable to access media object returned from instagram hashtag search api

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to get the media from instagram hashtag search api, i am getting the response correctly but i am unable to access the media object. it says

```
   "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '18001051678085904' does not 
     exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support 
     this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at 
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
```

this is how i am query `18001051678085904?fields=id,media_type,media_url` where `18001051678085904` is the media object i get from response of instagram hashtag search api, also i have the permission of public content access and instagram basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need 2 id's to get it working.

1. hashtag id
2. page id(facebook graph: instagram business account id)

graph query explorer:

v3.1/**hashtag_id**/recent_media?fields=id,caption,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink,comments_count&user_id=**page_id**;

URL to hit: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/hashtag_id/recent_media?access_token=access_token&fields=id,caption,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink,comments_count&user_id=page_id;

Please note that you can either search for recent_media or top_media

Let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: i am getting the media,thats not the problem, it shows the data array with id's of media object, but i am unable to access media object, when i try to access media object it shows this error

Comment: you can't access the media object, you will only be able to get limited number of fields in the data array which contains the media object id's from the facebook graph api. It's one of the limitations of instagram-hashtag endpoint using facebook graph api.

Comment: i dont get it so what the use of this api if it is not giving anything, just tell me what can i get from the array returned by querry u mentioned above.

Comment: i just want the images from result

Comment: v3.1/hashtag_id/recent_media?fields=<options>

options are as follows:
1. id: as you are not the owner you can't do anything except for reference if you store it on your system in some db
2. media_url: image url link
3. permalink: image code, can be used to create link to instagram eg: instagram.com/p/<permalink>
or it can also be used to fetch image if you use the following url for image:
https://www.instagram.com/p/<permalink>/media?size=l

other options are self explainatory in the link given above

Comment: thanks i got now what to do with it from your last answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Nitin Tokas answer, the fields you can request with the hashtag search are

```
/top_media?user_id=#####&fields=id,caption,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink
```

(see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/top-media)

Attempting to access other fields like username or timestamp makes the request fail with

> "message": "(#100) Please read documentation for supported fields"

And indeed, trying to access each resulting media individually fails with

> "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID ### does not
>   exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
>   support this operation"